# Write access on mounting a Windows network share

Tags: debian, networking, mount

I installed cifs-utils, and can mount the remote drive using the command

```
sudo mount.cifs //DRIVE ~/homedir/ -o user=user,pass=pass,sec=ntlmssp
```

However, the user account cannot write to the mounted folder, despite the fact that there are no access restrictions on the server side after inputting the credentials.

```
sudo mount.cifs //DRIVE ~/homedir/ -o user=user,pass=pass,sec=ntlmssp,umask=000
```

still does not work.

More strangely though, attempting to run the aforementioned commands as user results in `mount.cifs: command not found`

What would be the correct command to mount the folder so it is writeable by user?

Comment: You need to specify that the user account has write access to the mount point. Read the manual page for mount.cifs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make ordinary user to operate with remote share you should add the user's id to the option like

```
sudo mount.cifs //DRIVE ~/homedir/ -o user=user,pass=pass,sec=ntlmssp,uid=1000,gid=46
```

where

- `uid`  - user id which can found in `id` command output
- `guid` - user group id ( but in some case you'd better use `plugdev` group which equal 46)

Comment: Okay, but is there any explanation for the umask options failing to work, and the user not being able to access the mount command at all?

Comment: @MarchHo `umask` works for **new** files which you will made after mounting. Mounting is a *system* operation which allow just to administrator so did not allowed for ordinary user. More over such user is to operate just inside of his home directory.